# How to redirect a user to a different page based on the number of form entries in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to redirect a user based on whether or not they have an entry in a form. I am using formidable plugin. I set the variable $count to be a global variable but for some reason I can't get it to work outside of the function `check_entry_countt`. When I print it outside the variable, it returns a NULL value.

To avoid this, I decided to use the `my_logged_in_redirect()` function inside the `check_entry_countt` function but then the redirect function also stops working.

To get this code to work properly, I have two ways, whichever works better.

1. To use the redirect function `my_logged_in_redirect()` inside the `check_entry_countt` function so that it accesses the `$count` variable.
2. To use the redirect function `my_logged_in_redirect()` outside the `check_entry_countt` function but then get the function to access the $count variable as a global variable (which is not working for me).
   The code.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );
nocache_headers();


add_action('frm_display_form_action', 'check_entry_countt', 8, 3);
function check_entry_countt($params, $fields, $form){
  global $user_ID;
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  remove_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
  if( $form->id == 4 && !is_admin() && user_can( $current_user, "booknetic_staff" ) ){ //replace 4 or 5 with the ID of your form
    global $count;
    $count = FrmEntry::getRecordCount("form_id=". $form->id ." AND user_id=".$user_ID); 
    if($count >= 1){ //change 1 to your entry limit
      echo 'You have already submitted your data. Please visit your profile/account if you want to update';
      add_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
    } elseif ($count == 0) {
      //i need to run the redirect function here
    }
  }

}
```

The redirect function

```
  function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    
    if ( (is_front_page() || is_page('profile') || is_page('account'))  && is_user_logged_in()) 
    {
      
        wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/'); 
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

The goal: So that `elseif ($count == 0) { //i can run the redirect function}` as shown in the code.

If I was able to fetch the value of the global variable $count, inside my redirect function, I'd simply add the variable inside the if statement as so:

`if ( ($count == 0 && is_front_page() || is_page('profile') || is_page('account'))  && is_user_logged_in()){...}`
Whichever options works, either fetching the global variable outside `check_entry_countt` function or making my redirect function `my_logged_in_redirect()` work inside the `check_entry_countt` function, I'm fine. Currently, the global variable $count is being identified as undefined outside.

Clarification - When I say the redirect function also stops working I mean this:

The redirect function is working outside the `check_entry_countt function`. No redirection happens when I insert the redirect function inside this if statement `elseif ($count == 0) { // the redirect function stops redirecting when added here }`

Answer (score 0):

Normally from the `my_logged_in_redirect()` function; Use must work properly
Consider my example:

**The first example:**

```
add_action('frm_display_form_action', 'check_entry_countt', 8, 3);
function check_entry_countt($params, $fields, $form)
{
    global $user_ID;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    remove_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
    if ($form->id == 4 && !is_admin() && user_can($current_user, "booknetic_staff")) { //replace 4 or 5 with the ID of your form
        $count = FrmEntry::getRecordCount("form_id=" . $form->id . " AND user_id=" . $user_ID);
        if ($count >= 1) { //change 1 to your entry limit
            echo 'You have already submitted your data. Please visit your profile/account if you want to update';
            add_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
        } elseif ($count == 0) {

            my_logged_in_redirect();
            
        }
    }

}
```

The redirect function

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    
    if ( (is_front_page() || is_page('profile') || is_page('account'))  && is_user_logged_in()) 
    {
      
        wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/'); 
        die;
    }
}
```

Remove this hook :

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

---

**The second example**
If this does not work, set the value with the parameter :

```
add_action('frm_display_form_action', 'check_entry_countt', 8, 3);
function check_entry_countt($params, $fields, $form)
{
    global $user_ID;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    remove_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
    if ($form->id == 4 && !is_admin() && user_can($current_user, "booknetic_staff")) { //replace 4 or 5 with the ID of your form
        $count = FrmEntry::getRecordCount("form_id=" . $form->id . " AND user_id=" . $user_ID);
        if ($count >= 1) { //change 1 to your entry limit
            echo 'You have already submitted your data. Please visit your profile/account if you want to update';
            add_filter('frm_continue_to_new', '__return_false', 50);
        }
        my_logged_in_redirect($count);
    }

}



function my_logged_in_redirect($count)
{
    if (!empty($count) && $count == 0 && ((is_front_page() || is_page('profile') || is_page('account')) && is_user_logged_in())) {
        wp_redirect('/first-time-application-temp/');
        die;
    }

}

add_action('template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect');
```

For the second example, because the condition is inside the function, we do not need to check here

Comment: Two issues occur. 1. When i put the function ```my_logged_in_redirect(); ```  inside the if statement  ```elseif ($count == 0) {my_logged_in_redirect(); }```  the redirection works even when the $count is NOT equal to 0 which shouldn't be the case. The second case is that it generates an error ```Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function my_logged_in_redirect(), 0 passed in``` for line ```function my_logged_in_redirect($count)```

Comment: @Dan Hello again
Regarding the first problem add_action ('template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect'); Delete.
You are calling the function independently within your condition so you will not need the add_action hook

Comment: I corrected my answer, I hope it is practical

Comment: From your updated answer. In the first example, the redirection does not work completely. The second example - It redirects well but the issue is that it's redirecting even when the $count is NOT equal to 0.

Comment: In the second example where you have used $count in the if statement, I tried to var_dump the result of $count and it returns ```string(0) ""``` which seems to me like the $count variable doesn't work outside where it was declared which is the reason why it's redirecting even when the $count is not equal to 0.

Comment: Forgive me.
The value 0 equals the empty value, so we first reject the empty value. I corrected it again

Comment: Or we can use $ count === 0 instead of $ count == 0 in the second example. This operator only accepts integer values.

Comment: Not yet. Tried to use the comparison operator but still did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245262/discussion-between-morteza-barati-and-dan).